LaunchDaemon on macOS Sonoma can't issue commands that do sudo -u
I've got an in-house software running as root, configured to start as a LaunchDaemon in macOS. This software will run various other programs, some while doing sudo -u .
This setup stopped working with macOS Sonoma 15.1, and I fail to find any documentation on it (except ChatGPT telling me that "some security policies changed" without being able to get me any more specifics).
I have managed to work around the problem by replacing the binary invoked by launchctl with a script that do ssh to localhost, and starts the software.
Since sshd clearly is allowed to do what I need, I suspect the problem is in my launch deamon's configuration. But I can't for love nor money figure it out.
Anyone got ideas?

ChatGPT can‘t help you with things younger than itself (and often not even with older stuff). Can you enable logging in your launchd plist and check whether sudo throws a meaningful error text?

It doesn't, just returns 255 (operation not permitted).

Does su -l USER work better? Otherwise, can you please create a small example consisting of a launchd.plist and the script called from it which shows the problem, and add this to the question?

No, it is the entire sudo command that seems blocked. It doesn't even start with bad parameters.

Does it work if you interactively run sudo -s to become root, and then sudo -u … from root?
